# how i can resolve Error while merging dex archives?

Tags: android, parse-platform

Im getting this error in Build panel :

```
* What went wrong:
Execution failed for task ':app:mergeExtDexDebug'.
> com.android.build.api.transform.TransformException: java.lang.RuntimeException: java.lang.RuntimeException: com.android.builder.dexing.DexArchiveMergerException: Error while merging dex archives: 
  Program type already present: com.parse.AbstractQueryController$1
```

after adding this library  implementation 'com.parse:parse-livequery-android:1.0.6' to my existing implementations that they were these :

```
  implementation fileTree(include: ['*.jar'], dir: 'libs')
    implementation 'androidx.appcompat:appcompat:1.1.0-alpha02'
    implementation 'com.google.android.material:material:1.1.0-alpha04'
    implementation 'com.google.android.gms:play-services:11.4.0'
    implementation 'androidx.cardview:cardview:1.0.0'
    implementation 'androidx.constraintlayout:constraintlayout:2.0.0-alpha3'
    testImplementation 'junit:junit:4.12'
    androidTestImplementation 'androidx.test:runner:1.1.2-alpha01'
    androidTestImplementation 'androidx.test.espresso:espresso-core:3.1.2-alpha01'
    //image_view_cornered_lib
    implementation 'com.github.siyamed:android-shape-imageview:0.9.3@aar'
    //circle image view lib
    implementation 'de.hdodenhof:circleimageview:2.2.0'
    //parse libs here
    implementation 'com.github.parse-community.Parse-SDK-Android:parse:1.19.0'
    implementation 'com.github.parse-community.Parse-SDK-Android:fcm:1.19.0'
    implementation 'com.github.parse-community.Parse-SDK-Android:ktx:1.19.0'
```

Comment: can you add the dependencies tree here? 
you can generate one with this command  `./gradlew app:dependencies`

Answer (score 1):

`com.parse.AbstractQueryController` module is used by multiple library

in your case it must be
`com.parse:parse-livequery-android:1.0.6` and `com.github.parse-community.Parse-SDK-Android:parse:1.19.0`

To find the list of dependencies for the module app (default module's name for the app) we can do a

> gradlew app:dependencies

to retrieve a list of all the libraries.

after you found module that used twice with different versions exclude it like this

```
implementation ('com.parse:parse-livequery-android:1.0.6') {
    exclude module: 'duplicated module'
}
```

Answer (score 1):

Did you try this:

in **app/build.gradle:**

```
android {
    defaultConfig {
       multiDexEnabled true
    }
}
```

Comment: i don't think so 
it isn't hit 64K reference limit